# RandomForestRegressor - K-fold CV cross_val_predict never complete

Tags: python, random-forest, cross-validation, k-fold

I'm using RandomForestRegressor to generate new features:

The old script takes 20 mins to complete but still completed...

```
**param_grid = { 
    'n_estimators': [10, 50, 100, 1000],
    'max_depth' : [4,5,6,7,8],
}

def rfr_model(X, Y):
```

--Perform Grid-Search

```
gsc = GridSearchCV(
estimator=RandomForestRegressor(),
param_grid=param_grid,
cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', verbose=0, n_jobs=-1)

grid_result = gsc.fit(X, Y)
best_params = grid_result.best_params_

rfr = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=best_params["max_depth"], n_estimators=best_params["n_estimators"], 
                            random_state=False, verbose=False)
```

--Perform K-Fold CV

```
MSE = cross_val_score(rfr, X, Y, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
return MSE
```

However now I want to show my predicted values too so I added cross_val_predict and the model never completes:

```
# Perform K-Fold CV
    MAE = cross_val_score(rfr, X, Y, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error')
    MSE = cross_val_score(rfr, X, Y, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
    prediction = cross_val_predict(rfr, X, Y, cv=5)
    return print("MAE: ",MAE), print("MSE: ",MSE), prediction
```

Both run on:

```
**X2=pd.concat([x_test,x_train]) 
Y2=pd.concat([y_test,y_train])
X2 = X2.astype('float64')
Y2 = Y2.astype('float64').values.ravel()**
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Ps: I'm a beginner so pls be easy on me.